# Google maps kml file in android

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

In my android app when I try to get KML file using below URL it gives me wrong KML file which is having wrong coordinates. Starting coordinate also wrong. Please someone help me with this.

here is my url,

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=6.842001,79.911102&daddr=7.145981,80.285752&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml

the kml file coordinates starts with "79.910970,6.842550"

Answer (score 1):

It takes 0 seconds to move from `6.842001,79.911102 to 6.842550, 79.910970`

So what Google probably did is moved the starting point to the center of the road, as per its map matching algorithm

Comment: No it can't be 0 seconds because I have checked both points in a map there is a huge difference between these points. Is there any other way to get all these point in the kml file. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: [Check it out yourself](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=6.842001,79.911102&daddr=6.842550,+79.910970&hl=en&sll=6.842549,79.91097&sspn=0.001491,0.001918&geocode=FZFmaAAdvljDBA%3BFbZoaAAdOljDBA&vpsrc=0&mra=ltm&t=h&z=19)

Comment: Reno is right. Since you are asking routing directions google will snap to the nearest point on a ROAD. This point is in this case approx 60 meters from your specified starting point. (The 0 secs part is not relevant though)